# CC'ing using AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

Im trying to use AMPSCRIPT in the CC portion of the Journey. Since understanding Ampscript reads top down, and I can't declare the CC field in the body of the content, I have tried using these two Lookup Formula's with no success. Additionally, I know the emails are sending because I have added a static email address as the 3rd CC recipient for these tests. Below are the two formula's I'm using on separate CC lines:

`%%=Lookup("ent.Opportunity_Salesforce","On_Deck_Sales_Agent_Email__c","Id",@OpportunityID)=%%`

OR

`%%=v(Lookup("ent.Opportunity_Salesforce", "On_Deck_Sales_Agent_Email__c",”Id”,Attributevalue(“OpportunityID”)))=%%`

*FYI I wasn't using the 2nd way until I stumbled upon the below post showing me that format.
https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/cc-bcc-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud

Comment: Resolved this: 
%%=v(Lookup("ent.Opportunity_Salesforce","On_Deck_Sales_Agent_Email__c","Id",Attributevalue("opportunityid")))=%%

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this:

```
%%=v(Lookup("ent.Opportunity_Salesforce","On_Deck_Sales_Agent_Email__c","Id",Attributevalue("opportunityid")))=%%
```